# errors coerce not changing unwanted string to NaN in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, string, nan

I have a dataset which contains an undesirable string (which indicates a measurement was not able to be made). I want to change these unwanted strings to 'NaN's when the text file of data is read by pandas as the presence of a string is turning the data type of an otherwise int column to string. If there is a better process to this please let me know. When I try and use methods I have found on another question ([Change data type of columns in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15891038/change-data-type-of-columns-in-pandas)) they break at the point the unwanted string is found or else they seem to skip over the string altogether.

***Code***

```
import pandas as pd 
data = {
    'ID': [1,2,3,4],
    'V': [6.6,2.01,'tND - 7777',7.01],
    'A': [33,31,'tND - 88881',35]    
    } 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['ID','V','A'])

print(df)
df.astype({"V": int})
print(df)
# returns ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'tND - 7777'

pd.to_numeric(df['V'], errors = 'coerce')
pd.to_numeric(df['A'], errors = 'coerce')
print(df)
# returns original array, unwanted strings still in place
```

***Unwanted strings***

```
'tND - 7777','tND - 88881'
```

***Desired outcome***
Data in the dataframe columns which are ints (I am assuming a NaN is considered an int, I just need to plot the data once the strings are no longer present).

Comment: `pd.to_numeric` returns the series; it has no effect on the original underlying data. You need to assign the column back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assign output back:

```
df['V'] = pd.to_numeric(df['V'], errors = 'coerce')
df['A'] = pd.to_numeric(df['A'], errors = 'coerce')
```

Another idea is use:

```
df[['V','A']] = df[['V','A']].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors = 'coerce')
```

Comment: Smashing my head into the desk, how did I not see that! Thank you jezrael, will accept as soon as it lets me.